# How to use Excel VBA to list sent Outlook emails after set date?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to list all Outlook emails that I sent after a set date. After inputting the date into cell A1, I've been trying to use the following VBA.

```vb
Sub SentMail()

Dim Lastrow As Long
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

Range("A2:D" & Lastrow).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
Range("A1").Select

i = 2

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
    If OutlookMail.SentOn >= Range("A1").Value Then
        Range("A" & i).Value = OutlookMail.SentOn
        Range("B" & i).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("C" & i).Value = OutlookMail.To
        Range("D" & i).Value = OutlookMail.CC
        
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I receive

> run-time error 438: "Object doesn't support this property or method.

It works if the Default Folder is "olFolderInbox," but doesn't work if it is "olFolderSentMail."

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Are you getting an error? If not, have you tried to step through your code and check in the debugger why the condition is not satisfied?

Comment: I receive run-time error 438: "Object doesn't support this property or method."

Comment: On which line of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Never loop through all items in a folder - it will take minutes if the folder contains thousands of items, especially if the cached mode is off. Use Items.Restrict. In your particular case, that would be something like

```
For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items.Restrict("[SentOn] > '9/13/2023' ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify an item is a mailitem before returning a mailitem property.

One possible test:

```
If TypeName(OutlookItem) = "MailItem" Then
```

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SentMail()

Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Early binding requires reference to Outlook XX.X Object Library
Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace

Dim OutlookFolder As Outlook.Folder

Dim OutlookItem As Object
Dim OutlookMail As Outlook.MailItem

Dim i As Long

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set OutlookFolder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

Range("A2:D" & Lastrow).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A1").Select

i = 2

For Each OutlookItem In OutlookFolder.Items

    ' Verify OutlookItem is a mailitem before returning a mailitem property
    If TypeName(OutlookItem) = "MailItem" Then
    
        Set OutlookMail = OutlookItem
        
        If OutlookMail.SentOn >= Range("A1").Value Then
            Range("A" & i).Value = OutlookMail.SentOn
            Range("B" & i).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
            Range("C" & i).Value = OutlookMail.To
            Range("D" & i).Value = OutlookMail.CC
            
            i = i + 1
        End If
    End If
    
Next OutlookItem

Set OutlookFolder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```